# How can I avoid the Handyman's ground pound?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

The Handyman in *Bioshock Infinite* has a rather annoying attack in which he slams his fists into the ground, causing an electrical shockwave.

This attack not only decimates my shield and a good portion of my health, but it also seems entirely unavoidable. I've tried side-stepping, jumping, and putting some distance between us. None of this seems to work. He's even managed to hit me with it while I was *behind him*.

**How can I avoid this ground pound attack?**

Comment: Have you tried jumping just before he does it? I know things can get hectic during battle.

Comment: I have. I've tried jumping over the wave as it approaches, too. No luck. =(

Comment: Return to Sender will prevent you from taking any damage from his attacks. Just spawn a new shield after he attacks you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fighting Handymen effectively generally requires at least one of two things (both are preferable): mobility and superior firepower. Keep skylines and freight hooks in mind whenever you fight Handymen and escape whenever they get close. Close-quarters combat with a Handyman is typically a Not A Good Thing™.

Superior firepower generally involves weapons with high burst damage (shotguns, volley guns, RPGs, etc.) and low reliance on accuracy (not sniper rifles). You will want to aim for the Handyman's heart as this will stun him and interrupt his ground pound on the off chance he's in your face and there's no easy escape nearby.

If you don't keep these two tips in mind when you fight Handymen, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Devils Kiss and the shotgun works wonders on the Handyman.

Comment: Also Shock jockey and the carbine are a good combo against the patriots.